# Recent bluetooth signal strength drop

Tags: bluetooth

I used to walk out of my apartment, walk down three floors and across the parking lot before my Bluetooth signal disconnected. Now I have to hold the phone at chest level or sound starts to stutter if I lower phone to waist level.

It's not the headphones because my Sony speaker brick also lost range.

This started about a month ago and I wonder if it was because I installed the SMS Pro Messenger app? Or are they like Apple and wrote a routine to lower signal strength after you owned the phone for two years?

How does one go about analyzing if it's hardware signal strength problem or firmware related? I'm not adverse to resetting factory settings but don't want to reinstall everything if there is no chance of improving situation.

- Phone: Alcatel OneTouch Idol 3 5.5".
- Model Number: 6045I
- OS: Android 6.0.1
- Android Security Patch Level: November 1, 2016
- Kernel: 3.10-49-ga7fff7c
- Build Number: 7VGE-UDE1

Comment: Apartment buildings pose particular problems for signal consistency. New tenants, maybe? Some things configured differently? I wouldn't look for the "Apple reduced capability" conspiracy theory first.

Comment: @wbogacz It's not just in the apartment building it's everywhere outside, different places, traveling. I'm hoping to find a function that displays all apps that are hooked into the bluetooth services. Then remove those apps one by one to see if performance is restored.